# Rsync cropping symlink in transit

Tags: linux, symlink, rsync

I have two directories of which files are linked together with symlinks.

i.e. /directory1/files/file_a.txt to /directory1/directory2/files/file_a.txt

to symlink to eachother I build them so they are of the format ../../files/file_a.txt

The symlink is fine on my host server however not fine on my client server and is cropping the symlink to ../files/file_a.txt

meaning the full path isnt present and it is erroring.

My rsync command is

```
/bin/nice -n 15 /usr/bin/rsync -a -v -r --partial -ogp -l -H --delete --delay-updates --exclude=activated --exclude current/  -e "ssh -F **path to ssh config file**" $package->getDir().'/files '.$package->getDir().'/'.$package->getDate().' root@'. $client->getAddress().'::triplecast/'.$package->getId().'_'.preg_replace("/[^0-9a-zA-Z\-\'_]/", "", $package->getName()). "
```

Any ideas on what might be happening

Comment: first of all, don't '--delete' until you are absolutely sure you didn't do any typos... otherwise, depending on trailing "/" in source/destination, rsync may wipe out complete trees trying to make both similar...

Comment: and i think this could help : http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49791/how-to-rsync-a-chroot-without-breaking-symlinks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that it was missing the forward slash from  root@$client->getAddress().'::triplecast/'.

I have now changed it to

root@'. $client->getAddress().':/triplecast/'

no idea why that made a difference, if you know why please comment below.